# What is the best way to optimize images with Retina & non retina displays?

Tags: html, css

From my research, I understand you want to double the size of your images to make it look sharp on retina displays.

For a picture with a size of 500X500 px , I want to store them with a size of 1000X1000.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem now is that by using Google pagespeed insights, it gives my a very bad score for not optimizing images size to what they should be, suggesting to cut them down back to, say, 500X500 in the previous example.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: you compress your image here and check https://tinypng.com/...

Comment: Optimzilla will give you a compressed version with a choice of compression: https://imagecompressor.com/

Answer (score 1):

Usually having pretty big file sizes are results in slow loading web-pages. I'd recommend that you use a image compressor to downscale the file size.

Try using https://compresspng.com/ since they can compress the file size up to 90% and still keep the quality of the image.

Compressing all images on my website has resulted in faster loading times, I have a 6 page website that loads in 0.6s due to the file size compression.

Hope this helps you out!